# get html source code

Tags: javascript, http, html

I am trying to put the html source code for any webpage in a string using Javascript.
Please tell me if i can do something else to solve my problem..
I am using the following code that i found from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript/4033310#4033310)

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
var xmlHttp = null;

xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
xmlHttp.send( null );
return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

I tried this in IE Firefox and Chrome but i always get the following source code which is the source code for "PAGE NOT FOUND" page..If you any other info please let me know in a comment..
What i am trying is to get html from any webpage like google.com and other webpages..If i can't do that then what can i do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>404 - PAGE NOT FOUND</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            body{padding:0;margin:0;font-family:helvetica;}
            #container{margin:20px auto;width:868px;}
            #container #top404{background-image:url('http://74.53.143.237/images/404top.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;width:868px;height:168px;}
            #container #mid404{background-image:url('http://74.53.143.237/images/404mid.gif');background-repeat:repeat-y;width:868px;}
            #container #mid404 #gatorbottom{position:relative;left:39px;float:left;}
            #container #mid404 #xxx{float:left;padding:40px 237px 10px;}
            #container #mid404 #content{float:left;text-align:center;width:868px;}
            #container #mid404 #content #errorcode{font-size:30px;font-weight:800;}
            #container #mid404 #content p{font-weight:800;}
            #container #mid404 #content #banner{margin:20px 0 0 ;}
            #container #mid404 #content #hostedby{font-weight:800;font-size:25px;font-style:italic;margin:20px 0 0;}
            #container #mid404 #content #coupon{color:#AB0000;font-size:22px;font-style:italic;}
            #container #mid404 #content #getstarted a{color:#AB0000;font-size:31px;font-style:italic;font-weight:800;}
            #container #mid404 #content #getstarted {margin:0 0 35px;}
            #container #bottom404{background-image:url('http://74.53.143.237/images/404bottom.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;width:868px;height:14px;}
            </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="top404"></div>
    <div id="mid404">

            <div id="gatorbottom"><img src="http://74.53.143.237/images/gatorbottom.png" alt="" /></div>
            <div id="xxx"><img src="http://74.53.143.237/images/x.png" alt="" /></div>
    <div id="content">
            <div id="errorcode">ERROR 404 - PAGE NOT FOUND</div>
            <p>Oops! Looks like the page you're looking for was moved or never existed.<br />Make sure you typed the correct URL or followed a valid link.</p>

            <div id="banner">

                    <object width="728" height="90"><param name="movie" value="http://74.53.143.237/images/hg728x90.swf">

                            <embed src="http://74.53.143.237/images/hg728x90.swf?clickTAG=http://secure.hostgator.com/cgi-bin/affiliates/clickthru.cgi?id=page404" width="728" height="90"></embed>
                    </object>
            </div>

            <div id="hostedby">This site is hosted by HostGator!</div>
            <div id="coupon">Build your website today for 1 cent!   Coupon code: "404PAGE"</div>

            <div id="getstarted"><a href="http://www.hostgator.com/?utm_source=internal&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=page404" title="HostGator Web Hosting" >CLICK HERE TO GET STARTED</a></div>

    </div>

    <div style="clear:left;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom404"></div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can't access the contents of a page on a different domain only by using client-side JavaScript.

Comment: That is because your URL is wrong. Check n fiddler or Chrome console to see what is the url that is sent and hit it in the browser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534640/ajax-origin-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin/15537999#15537999

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to put the html source code for any webpage in a string using Javascript

If by "any" you mean pages from origins other than the origin your document is served from, you can't do that from JavaScript *running in a browser*, because you're using an ajax call and those are restricted by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which says that (for instance) script running in a document on `http://stackoverflow.com` can't use ajax to load content from `http://example.com`. (An "origin" is more than just the domain name, there are several aspects to it, see the link for details).

Some of the pages you might request (but probably ***very*** few) might support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), in which case if they allow your origin (probably by allowing all origins), you could use ajax to load their content.

If you're running JavaScript *outside* the browser (NodeJS, SilkJS, RingoJS, Rhino, Windows Scripting Host, etc.), then the SOP wouldn't apply, but I suspect you'd probably need to use something other than the `XMLHttpRequest` object to do it.

But fundamentally, in a web page (not an extension/add-on) in a browser, you can't do that.

> ...but i always get the ... source code for "PAGE NOT FOUND" page

But *that* sounds like the URL is just wrong.

Comment: Yes by any i mean pages from different origins like google.com

Comment: "The policy ... prevents access to most methods and properties across pages on different sites." - From the link provided above

Comment: @Dchris: Then, as I said above, you can't.

Comment: @Dchris: Cross-origin stuff is quite locked down in browsers. You can put the content in the page using an `iframe`, but you can't *access* it in code (and a large number of sites use "frame busting" to avoid being framed that way). So basically, no, not really, not purely client-side. You can, of course, have your page query **your** server and ask your server to get the target page, then send it back to you. And you can [use YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax), but I expect there are limits to what you can do there.