# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Node / Apache Port Issue

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest, express, cors

i've created a small API using Node/Express and trying to pull data using Angularjs but as my html page is running under apache on localhost:8888 and node API is listen on port 3000, i am getting the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. I tried using  `node-http-proxy` and Vhosts Apache but not having much succes, please see full error and code below.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access."

```
// Api Using Node/Express    
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var contractors = [
    {   
     "id": "1", 
        "name": "Joe Blogg",
        "Weeks": 3,
        "Photo": "1.png"
    }
];

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.json(contractors);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server is running on Port 3000')
```

### Angular code

```
angular.module('contractorsApp', [])
.controller('ContractorsCtrl', function($scope, $http,$routeParams) {

   $http.get('localhost:3000').then(function(response) {
       var data = response.data;
       $scope.contractors = data;
   })
```

### HTML

```
<body ng-app="contractorsApp">
    <div ng-controller="ContractorsCtrl"> 
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="person in contractors">{{person.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: potentially related: [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](/q/43871637/11107541)

Answer (score 838, accepted):

Try adding the following middleware to your NodeJS/Express app (I have added some comments for your convenience):

```
// Add headers before the routes are defined
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

(You might need to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.)

Comment: Can you help specify exactly where that goes?  I have the following code in my server.  Does it go right after this?

var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
  , request = require("request")
  , url = require("url");
server.listen(6969);

// does it go here? on a new line?

Comment: It is a middleware function. You can put it after the `require` lines and before the `server.listen` line. Hope that helps!

Comment: @jvandemo do i have to change the app.get('/', function(req, res) to ...function(req, res, next) ?

Comment: @SangramSingh Yes, the `next` argument is optional but you need to specify it in case you use it inside your function.

Comment: You are my favorite person ever right now. Thank you. Can we add a note that this code has to happen before the routes are defined for noobs like me?

Comment: What if i am using 3rd Party API ? I can't add "Allow Access" on their server. You are showing example of local project. I am having same issue but with my request is goes to another website url. How to fix it any idea ?

Comment: @Gurpinder - CORS was created to prevent client from unauthorized access. If you want to have access, you need the 3rd party app owner to add you to his authorized users. Else I can simply create my own MyGoogle website, provide search query, and present the results as my own.

Comment: @gegillam -> Thanks for your comment. I was adding this line after the routes were defined. :/ It works fine after putting the above code, just after creating the app object.

Comment: How to make this work while using the request module?

Comment: @RohitTigga did you ever find how to get this working with `request`?

Comment: Wow buddy this is the ultimate hat trick, thanks man, I would never guess this solution.

Comment: It did not work in my case. Still getting this error: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://abc.xyz.net:212' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Comment: perfect, for testing I replaced 'http://localhost:8888' with '*' not safe, but great for testing

Comment: @JohanHoeksma is there a reason why that isn't so safe? How did you setup for production?

Comment: So any origin can connect now. For a localhost it's not a problem.
On a server I think you don't want it...

Comment: Thank you - I was tearing my hair out trying to get this working. Worth noting that the website is case sensitive.

Comment: I wish I bumped into this 4 hours ago!

Comment: How to fix this in hapiJS

Comment: I ran into this problem with a POST request but it had to do with the upload size being too large.  It was a very misleading error.

Comment: How do we allow for all origins instead of just localhost:8888 ?
Is adding an asterisk instead of url like res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); a valid way ?

Comment: this worked thaks

Answer (score 139):

Accepted answer is fine, in case you prefer something shorter, you may use a plugin called **[cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)** available for Express.js.

It's simple to use, for this particular case:

```js
var cors = require('cors');

// use it before all route definitions
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8888'}));
```

(You might need to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.)

The request origin needs to match the allowed origin(s), and you can also have multiple of them:

```js
app.use(
  cors({origin: ['http://localhost:8888', 'http://127.0.0.1:8888']})
);
```

Comment: I had to use `{origin: 'null'}` for it to work... Apparently, my browser sends `null` as the origin?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel. I am always for a packaged solution compared to code snippet

Comment: sweet little library that handled my use case of wanting different methods from different origins quite nicely... and less code fatigue for the next guy looking at it.

Comment: Thanks, `app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));` worked for me, as per [enable-cors](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html).

Comment: I suggest having a look at the [npm cors page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to make better use of it.  It made things very clear for me =).

Comment: How to fixed this in HapiJS

Comment: I'm new, how to input multiple origin with above code?

Answer (score 45):

Another way, is simply add the headers to your route:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'); // If needed
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type'); // If needed
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true); // If needed

    res.send('cors problem fixed:)');
});
```

Comment: `)` of smiley confused me

Answer (score 23):

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311469/458193) worked fine for me, except that I needed to whitelist more than one domain.

Also, top answer suffers from the fact that `OPTIONS` request isn't handled by middleware and you don't get it automatically.

I store whitelisted domains as `allowed_origins` in Express configuration and put the correct domain according to `origin` header since `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't allow specifying more than one domain.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

function allowCrossDomain(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');

  var origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (_.contains(app.get('allowed_origins'), origin)) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.send(200);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.logger());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(allowCrossDomain);
});
```

Comment: Is this the same 'if (app.get('allowed origins').indexOf(origin)!==-1)?'?

Answer (score 16):

The answer code allow only to localhost:8888. This code can't be deployed to the production, or different server and port name.

To get it working for all sources, use this instead:

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me! " * is not a valid origin ". It seems the * character is not recognized as a wildcard.

Comment: It works for me. i.e. using wild card '*'. works both for chrome and safari.

Comment: Thanks ;) Works fine

Answer (score 15):

Install cors dependency in your project:

```
npm i --save cors
```

Add to your server configuration file the following:

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

It works for me with 2.8.4 cors version.

Comment: `"cors": "^2.8.5",
"express": "^4.16.3",` works fine just with the line @monikaja suggested. Thanks!

Comment: What this does is to enable all origins/domains to access the app which is something you usually don't want to do. Instead specify just the allowed domains.

Comment: After 4-5 hours of searching, this is the only solution that actually works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Hi this happens when the front end and backend is running on different ports. The browser blocks the responses from the backend due to the absence on CORS headers. The solution is to make add the CORS headers in the backend request. The easiest way is to use cors npm package.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

This will enable CORS headers in all your request. For more information you can refer to cors documentation

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send('hello world')
})
```

You can change * to fit your needs. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 10):

All the other answers didn't work for me. (including cors package, or setting headers through middleware)

For socket.io 3^ this worked without any extra packages.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a best reply ever! Worked with socketio. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
app.all('*', function(req, res,next) {
    /**
     * Response settings
     * @type {Object}
     */
    var responseSettings = {
        "AccessControlAllowOrigin": req.headers.origin,
        "AccessControlAllowHeaders": "Content-Type,X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5,  Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name",
        "AccessControlAllowMethods": "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
        "AccessControlAllowCredentials": true
    };

    /**
     * Headers
     */
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", responseSettings.AccessControlAllowCredentials);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  responseSettings.AccessControlAllowOrigin);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", (req.headers['access-control-request-headers']) ? req.headers['access-control-request-headers'] : "x-requested-with");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", (req.headers['access-control-request-method']) ? req.headers['access-control-request-method'] : responseSettings.AccessControlAllowMethods);

    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.send(200);
    }
    else {
        next();
    }


});
```

Comment: Isn't this approach much simpler? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40820322/5035986

Answer (score 4):

Add following code in app.js of NODEJ Restful api to avoid "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error in angular 6 or any other framework

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//enables cors
app.use(cors({
  'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
  'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
  'origin': '*',
  'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  'preflightContinue': false
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use cors package to handle it.

```
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

for setting the specific origin

```
app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:8080'}));
```

[know more](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use "$http.jsonp"

OR

Below is the work around for chrome for local testing

You need to open your chrome with following command. (Press window+R)

```
Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Note : Your chrome must not be open. When you run this command chrome will open automatically.

If you are entering this command in command prompt then select your chrome installation directory then use this command.

Below script code for open chrome in MAC with "--allow-file-access-from-files"

```
set chromePath to POSIX path of "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome" 
set switch to " --allow-file-access-from-files"
do shell script (quoted form of chromePath) & switch & " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

second options

You can just use [open(1)](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) to add the flags: open -a 'Google Chrome' --args --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: How about on MAC ??  Chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files

Comment: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files    manage to open chrome but the message is still showing "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "

Comment: +1 I can confirm this works with the Mac option using 'open'. My case is a little different as I'm simply testing a completely downloaded site that accesses some local JSON files.

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * Allow cross origin to access our /public directory from any site.
 * Make sure this header option is defined before defining of static path to /public directory
 */
expressApp.use('/public',function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});


/**
 * Server is about set up. Now track for css/js/images request from the 
 * browser directly. Send static resources from "./public" directory. 
 */
expressApp.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

```html
If you want to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to a specific static directory you can set the following.
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all listed answers, I had the same error

I have both access to frontend and backend, I already added **cors** module `app.use(cors());` Still, I was struggling with this error.

After some debugging, I found the issue. When I upload a media which size was more than 1 MB then the error was thrown by **Nginx server**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>413 Request Entity Too Large</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>413 Request Entity Too Large</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>

</html>
```

But in the console of frontend, I found the error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.yourbackend.com' from origin 'https://web.yourfromntend.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So It makes confusion here. But the route cause of this error was from **nginx** configuration. It's just because the directive `client_max_body_size` value has been set to **0** by default. It determines what the allowable HTTP request size can be is `client_max_body_size`. This directive may already be defined in your **nginx.conf** file located at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` Now you need to add/edit the value of the directive `client_max_body_size` either at `http` or `server`.

```
server {
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    ...
}
```

Once you have set your desired value, save your changes and reload **Nginx**: `service nginx reload`

After these changes, It's working well

**REFERENCE**: [https://www.keycdn.com/support/413-request-entity-too-large#:~:text=%23,processed%20by%20the%20web%20server.&text=An%20example%20request%2C%20that%20may,e.g.%20a%20large%20media%20file](https://www.keycdn.com/support/413-request-entity-too-large#:%7E:text=%23,processed%20by%20the%20web%20server.&text=An%20example%20request%2C%20that%20may,e.g.%20a%20large%20media%20file)).

Answer (score 0):

We'll see if the top 2 answers accept my edit, but it's very likely you're gonna have to either add or use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.

With the `cors` package, you're even able to use more than one allowed origin:

```js
app.use(
  cors({ origin: ["http://localhost:8888", "http://127.0.0.1:8888"] })
);
```

And you could use `origin: "*"` if you wish to allow for anything.

For more info, do check out [Web Dev Simplified's tutorial](https://youtu.be/PNtFSVU-YTI).

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is probably fine. I haven't tried it. I preferred to use `cors`.

However, **the simpler usage of `cors` mentioned here didn't work for me**. It shouldn't work for you too as expected if you test it closely i.e. then you should be able to access from any domain and not only limited to whitelisted ones which it should be, i.e. it will look like it is working as you can access your backend but not only from the whitelisted domains as expected but any. I noticed that even though I was `whitelisting` only specific domains using the simpler method,
<del>`app.use(cors({origin: ['http://localhost:8888', 'http://127.0.0.1:8888']}));`</del>
or some other similar solution, I was literally able to access my backend from any domain (using thunder client, bash command, custom `origin` value, or even from another not-whitelisted machine). There is no mention of such exact example of simple usage in [**cors**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) documentation as well (as of now) that skips the usage of `corsOptions` or such middleware.

But then I came up with this solution that is working as expected i.e. now I can only access from `whitelisted` domains and not from others.

Click **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77258686/13607767)** to find a detailed answer on how to use `cors` to whitelist specific domains i.e. allow only specific domains to access your backend endpoints securely. In your case, you will only need to modify this - `ALLOWED_ORIGINS=https://foo.example1 https://foo.example2` to this - `ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://localhost:8888 http://127.0.0.1:8888`

I have used `cors` recently. This is the better way which I could come up with that works well, has better control and security.