# Roles and locking down endpoints in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to build a REST api for my game. Since I am new to this, I have having a difficult time trying to figure out how I can "lock down" endpoints. In the sense that, I don't want just anyone making a post request to my game scores endpoint and updating it. What would be the best solution to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is an authorization process, a common implementation is an ACL (Access Control List) where each request you make must include a token, that token is associated with a set of roles and each role has several permissions. On each request you check that token's permissions against the requests endpoint and see if the requester is allowed to execute the action.

There are packages to easy that implementation like [acl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acl).

If you don't want to spend much time doing that yourself I recommend taking a look at [Loopback](http://loopback.io/).

EDIT:

In your frontend application you could have something like:

```
app.all(['/api/*', '/fe/*'], function(req, res) {
    req.pipe(request({
        headers: { 'Authorization': process.env.AUTH_TOKEN },
        url: process.env.PROXY + req.url,
        method: req.method,
        body: req.body,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        withCredentials: true
    }))
    .on('error', function(e) {
        res.status(500).send(e);
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

What that code does is that it takes any request that starts with /api/ or /fe/ to your frontend and pipes them to your backend server (`process.env.PROXY`).

The key piece is the `process.env.AUTH_TOKEN`, you could use a random and big hash here. Then on each protected request your backend checks if the header matches the `AUTH_TOKEN` you selected.

The advantage of this is that the end user never seems that token, as a matter of fact the end user will only see requests that go to your frotend server.

Comment: Problem being, with what I am currently thinking, I need to send the scores from a client side app. Is there a secure way of locking down an endpoint only to one type of application? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `one type of application`. Do you mean that you only want to allow requests from your frontend app? If so you could use the [access-control headers] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18311469/3684203). But it isn't a bullet proof approach since someone could manually set the header

Comment: Exactly what I mean. How else would I be able to get around this problem? I.e a bullet proof method.