# Asp.net core doesn't respond to preflight request (OPTION) with proper headers of Access-Control-*?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've added the following code in the file `startup.cs`.

**In method: ConfigureServices:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

    var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    services.AddDbContext<Models.StaticDataContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddMvc(o => {});
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));
    services.AddCors(o=> { o.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin", b => b.WithOrigins("*")); });
    // Tried it without any parameter
    // services.AddCors(); 
}
```

**In method: Configure:**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();
    loggerFactory.AddNLog();

    env.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");

    app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

However it doesn't return the headers of `Access-Control-*`?

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:5001/api/Deal2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5001
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://localhost:8082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:8082/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

The raw response got from fiddler.

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2016 23:32:31 GMT
Server: Kestrel
```

And there should be some headers of the following?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: YOUR_DOMAIN
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Access-Control-Request-Headers: YOUR_CUSTOM_HEADERS
```

Comment: The options response has no content, that's why you probably get a 204.

Comment: question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem, but it might help.

IIS needs to handle the preflight OPTION requests for ASP.NET Core. There is more information on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108307/angular4-asp-net-core-1-2-windows-authentication-cors-for-put-and-post-gives-401/45545655#45545655).

My answer at the end and shows how to enable IIS to handle these requests.