# .Net Core CORS 401 POST/PUT

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Does anyone have experience of anonymous authentication and windows authentication with Web Api Core and CORS? Essentially I need Windows Authentication enabled, however when I do so CORS requests to PUT and POST fail due to the preflight request being rejected. I have enabled CORS properly using the below code but nothing seems to work.

```
            services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins(new string[] { "http://localhost:3000" })
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

The below question is exactly my situation but has an accepted answer which both doesn't work and has incorrect config data.
[Angular4 ASP.NET Core 1.2 Windows Authentication CORS for PUT and POST Gives 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108307/angular4-asp-net-core-1-2-windows-authentication-cors-for-put-and-post-gives-401)

Comment: did you find any solution? I've exactly the same setup and same issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate and Answer is here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50354772/946773

Answer (score 0):

You also need

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

in the `Configure` method.

Comment: I have it on the controllers so shouldn't need it in Configure