# Fetch with headers

Tags: reactjs, fetch

When use fetch for request in server using headers return

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at index.js:50
    at <anonymous>
```

Line of code 50 is }).then(res => res.json())

What can be wrong?

This code fetch.

```
fetch(api-url, {
          mode: 'no-cors',
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': ' application/json',
                        'X-API-SERVER': '85499f9f'
                    },
        }).then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200){
              console.log("accepted");
            }else {
              console.log(res.error);
            }

             console.log(res.error)
          }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: you can remove the comma on line 49

Comment: @Chris removing comma on line 49 not work

Comment: Your API endpoint is returning something other than valid JSON.

Comment: when the `fetch` response is successful, are you setting the `result` state to the given response?

Comment: @JoseAPL I am new to javascript as would be the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're requesting an API, you don't want to disable CORS. It's probably enough to just remove `mode: 'no-cors'` in your `fetch` request to fix this, as long as your API server sends the correct headers as well (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`).

Comment: when postman return ok but when fecth return this when remove no-cors.

Fetch API cannot load https://-app-dobled.herokuapp.com/api/v1/create. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
index.js:60 TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: Yes, exactly. [Set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311469/6941627) on your server's routes. You don't want to use `no-cors` here. It's a backend issue, not one on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

With `res.status` you're trying to retrieve the `status` property from the response body (as returned by the json() function), not the response object itself.