# Node js no access control allow origin answers from other questions don't work as well

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have node js server which you can view here - https://github.com/Inibua/ServerNodeJS

In `index.js` I have the following

```
 const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const passport = require('passport')
const localSignupStrategy = require('./passport/local-signup')
const localLoginStrategy = require('./passport/local-login')
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth')
const postRoutes = require('./routes/post')
const commentRoutes = require('./routes/comment')

const app = express()

const port = 5000

const envConfig = require('./config/environment')
require('./config/database')(envConfig)
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://roomy-hook.surge.sh');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(passport.initialize())
//app.use(cors())

passport.use('local-signup', localSignupStrategy)
passport.use('local-login', localLoginStrategy)

// routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes)
app.use('/post', postRoutes)
app.use('/comment', commentRoutes)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}...`)
})
```

the `app.use()` which addes `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is copied from here - [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Node / Apache Port Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue)

I have also tried the other questions as well, but it doesn't work.

I have tried

`app.use(cors())`

`app.use(cors({origin:"front-end-url"}))`

`app.use(cors({origin:null}))`

`app.use(cors({origin:"*"}))`

as stated in other answers, but nothing works.

Here is the error I get -

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

If you want to recreate it here is the url for the front-end http://roomy-hook.surge.sh Here you need to first press `Login` and fill the form and press "Sign up" on the console you will see the error.

If needed here is the route for `login and`signup`inside`routes/auth.js`

```
 const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const validator = require('validator')
const userController = require('../controllers/user')

const router = new express.Router()

function validateSignupForm (payload) {
  const errors = {}
  let isFormValid = true
  let message = ''

  if (!payload || typeof payload.password !== 'string' || payload.password.trim().length < 4) {
    isFormValid = false
    errors.password = 'Password must have at least 4 characters.'
  }

  if (!payload || typeof payload.username !== 'string' || payload.username.trim().length === 0) {
    isFormValid = false
    errors.name = 'Please provide your name.'
  }

  if (!isFormValid) {
    message = 'Check the form for errors.'
  }

  return {
    success: isFormValid,
    message,
    errors
  }
}

function validateLoginForm (payload) {
  const errors = {}
  let isFormValid = true
  let message = ''

  if (!payload || typeof payload.password !== 'string' || payload.password.trim().length === 0) {
    isFormValid = false
    errors.password = 'Please provide your password.'
  }

  if (!isFormValid) {
    message = 'Check the form for errors.'
  }

  return {
    success: isFormValid,
    message,
    errors
  }
}

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  const validationResult = validateSignupForm(req.body)
  if (!validationResult.success) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: false,
      message: validationResult.message,
      errors: validationResult.errors
    })
  }

  return passport.authenticate('local-signup', (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: err
      })
    }
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      user: req.body,
      message: 'You have successfully signed up! Now you should be able to log in.'
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  const validationResult = validateLoginForm(req.body)
  if (!validationResult.success) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: false,
      message: validationResult.message,
      errors: validationResult.errors
    })
  }

  return passport.authenticate('local-login', (err, token, userData) => {
    if (err) {
      if (err.name === 'IncorrectCredentialsError') {
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: false,
          message: err.message
        })
      }

      return res.status(200).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Could not process the form.'
      })
    }

    return res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'You have successfully logged in!',
      token,
      user: userData
    })
  })(req, res, next)

})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: Did you change something to the server? I just tried sign-up and it's giving `404 Not Found` instead of  No Access Control Allow

Comment: I try debugging it and sometimes I stop the server and rerun it. I just tried it and it gives the correct error. here is a screenshot http://prntscr.com/hqzd31

Comment: There might be something fishy with how the header handles your direct link to the site. Just try setting `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` instead of `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://roomy-hook.surge.sh');` to check if it works for `*`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `res.header` instead of `res.setHeader` or is it a typo? In other answers it is with `res.setHeader`

Comment: It works either way. Also, if that doesn't work, add the allowed `Origin` header in the allow-headers: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With,content-type')`;

Comment: On the server I have added the first response with the change to allow every url with `*` but it still doesn't work

Comment: I have also added the code from the answer inside `routes/auth.js` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Луцка you are forgetting the port `http://164.138.216.49` this address is pointing to IIS server and I guess your nodejs server is not running there. Try `http://164.138.216.49:nodejs_port/auth/login` where nodejs_port is the port on which your nodejs server is running

Comment: @codtex The port is 6969 and when I add the port into the request I get 502 Bad Gateway as well as missing Allow Access Control Origin error.

Comment: Луци this could be a variety of reasons. What I was going to do is setup a basic nodejs server with a sample `GET` path e.g. `http://164.138.216.49:6969/test` that simply returns `Hello world` and once I see the message, proceed with the complicated logic. The 502 error could be coming from the server configuration itself or IIS

Comment: @codtex I have a very basic route which is `/post/all` which is simple GET request which returns objects from the database. The problem is that it doesnt reach the `route`. Sadly I have no control over the server on which my app is hosted. I have messaged the support of my hosting provider to provide me with useful link, if he doesnt - Despite this I have no idea how I could change my code to work. There doesnt seem to be any error  in the code. I have checked every similar question and tried every possible option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `cors` in option in every url.

```
var cors = require('cors');    
router.options('/post', cors());
router.post('/post');
```

Comment: Where should I add this? In index.js I am not using router.options but I use it in `router/auth.js`

Comment: @ЛуциПетков add it in the above of every urls in the routes folder you need cors.if you are using the cors no need to put the extra cors object in app.use.

Comment: I added it to the server in `routes/auth.js` for routes `signup` and `login` and it still gives the same error