# Spotify authorization access control allow origin issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I've been trying to get the Spotify access control allow to work but, every time I try to get onto authorization page, it gives me the:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

problem. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, if anyone can help, that would be appreciated. I am using React with ES6 to do this as well if anyone was wondering.

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const request = require('request');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const env_client_id = process.env.client_id;
const env_client_id_secret = process.env.client_id_secret;
const redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:5000' || 'https://connectthrumusic.herokuapp.com/';

router.post('/getClientIDs', function(req, res, next) {
  res.json ({
    client_id: env_client_id,
    client_id_secret: env_client_id_secret
  })
});

router.get('/spotifyLogin', function(req, res, next) {
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: env_client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri
    }));
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const routes = require('./router/routes');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "docs")));

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("invalid");
});

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Running on Port: " + port);
});

app.use('/info', routes);
```

home.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      client_id: '',
      client_id_secret: ''
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getIds().then(result =>
      this.setState({
        client_id: result.client_id,
        client_id_secret: result.client_id_secret
      })
    )
  }

  getIds() {
      var fetchedId = fetch('/info/getClientIDs', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/JSON'}
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(function(parsedData) {
        return parsedData;
      })

      return fetchedId;
  }

  redir() {
    fetch('/info/spotifyLogin')
    .then(function(data) {
      //do nothing for now
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // If there is any error you will catch them here
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.redir}>Redirect</button>
        {this.state.client_id}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to set the proper headers in your server. [See this question for a possible solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue) [Also take a look at this question for a good explanation of the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you for answering kingdaro, however even after trying the possible solution it does not solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

it's Cross Origin Request Issue whereas port 5000 is not allowed to access the spotify API.

You can find an example of using express to perform the authentication flow with Spotify on https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples (see the authorization_code approach).

If it's not working, try changing your port into 8080 or 8888

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. After trying both ports.