# why post json data not receive in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

when i post json data on node server, it leads to error 
'Response to preflight request doest't pass access control check'
but when i post same request on php server it works .
[browser console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5rLC.png)

can someone tell me why this not working in node.js but
when i tried to post data through postman on node server now no error it works.

[postman picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcO2a.png)

here is my nodeJS code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/post', function(req, res){
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.send(req.body);
})
```

and this is request code that is send from browser

```
function callAjax(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:3010/post',
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    data: {
        email:'fake@mail.com'
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cors module first:-

```
npm install --save cors
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

Comment: not working but now error changes on client side 
' Failed to load http://localhost:3010/post: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.'

Comment: app.use(cors()) should be placed at top

Comment: now request sent with no error but return nothing. but when i `app.use(express.json());` uncomment it show me 400 bad request

Comment: try res.json(req.body) instead res.send(req.body) & if it solves accept my awnser

Comment: also use body-parser as someone has suggested in awnser to get (body)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));


app.post('/post', function(req, res){
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

   res.json(req.body);
});
```

Comment: still got error 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Comment: @IftikharHussain, I haven't seen the code before. Use `res.setHeader` instead of `res.header`. I have edited answer. Please check it.  REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue