# Unable to call JIRA Rest API in my application from Jira

Tags: angularjs, http, jira-rest-api

I am working on a AngularJS web application(`http://localhost:3000/` ) runs on a node.js server(on windows system) and for the application I need to access JIRA REST API(e.g `http://172.27.209.73:8080/rest/api/2/serverInfo` ) using AngularJS service(http Ajax call).

Now when I am trying accessing the API the request is could be made due the cross server origin issue

I can access the JIRA url from windows system now but whenever I am trying some API call to the url it doesn’t allowing to access the url and the below issue is showing

> “No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

JIRA is installed on Linux system using Docker Container.

Comment: try jsonp, may be will help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Node / Apache Port Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue)

Comment: @MandeepSingh used jsonp but giving me following error                                                                      Refused to execute script from 'My URL' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.