# Cross-Origin Request Blocked with React and Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cors

So I hit this error, when I was trying to send data to the back end using React. From what I learnt I need to allow the communication on the back-end and in the `.htaccess` file. Here are some of the links I used:

[No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - Node / Apache Port Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue)

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Both of them have code, but it didn't help.

So far my Server-side code is this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
});
```

This is my Client-side code:

```
sendMail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var contactReason = document.getElementById('contactReason').value;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var additionalInfo = document.getElementById('additionalInfo').value;
    var body = {
        name: name,
        contactReason: contactReason,
        email: email,
        additionalInfo: additionalInfo,
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body,
    }).then(r => console.log(r)).catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

So what am I missing? I do not have an `.htaccess` file, but I'm doing it all locally so I'm not sure if I can even use it.

It looks to me like I'm allowing all I need, but I guess it's not enough.

If you're going to mark as a duplicate, please at least make sure my issues are covered by the answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There's a node package called cors which makes it very easy.

$`npm install cors`

```
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

You don't need any config to allow all.

See the Github repo for more info: https://github.com/expressjs/cors

Answer (score 9):

One reason might be you're using the route as localhost:8000 rather than http://localhost:8000.

**USE**

```
http://localhost:8000
```

**DON'T USE**

```
localhost:8000
```

Comment: the browser should interpret these the same

Answer (score 5):

if you add this header

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

you're using credential mode (means you're sending some authentication cookie from your app) and as for CORS specification you cannot use the wildcard * in this mode.

you should change your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to match the specific host who generated the request

you can change this line:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

to

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'the ip address');
```

but to be more generic, something like this should work:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.header('origin') 
|| req.header('x-forwarded-host') || req.header('referer') || req.header('host'));
```

in addition you have even to allow OPTIONS requests from the browser otherwise you will get a preflight request error.

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS');
```

Answer (score 4):

To anyone else that this may help, I was using `axios` with `withCredentials: true`.

On my Express backend, I was simply doing,

```
app.use(cors())
```

What fixed it was either removing `withCredentials: true` from the React frontend or changing my backend to,

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true }))
```

Comment: This is what exactly we need to do to get it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

Added core with its options worked well(express V.4.18.2)

```
const cors = require('cors') 

const corsOptions = { 
  // origin:'https://abc.onrender.com',
  AccessControlAllowOrigin: '*',  
  origin: '*',  
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE' 
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

if you are sending authentication cookie/ login stuff from your app then add the API url for the origin as bellow.

```
 const cors = require('cors')

  const corsOptions = {
    AccessControlAllowOrigin: '*',
    origin: 'https://abc.onrender.com',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE'
  }
  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to allow `OPTIONS` method as well

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS');
```

the browser send it with any post request to other domain to check how it will communicate with this remote server.

Comment: Should I create an `OPTIONS` object or something like this?

Comment: No, just include it in the express header like shown above

Comment: No luck then. Any idea what the other problem might be?

Comment: Sorry I simply put the middleware in the wrong place. Thank you for the help anyway!