# server errors using express in a React project

Tags: reactjs, express, server

I'm working in a React app where I want to get data from an Express server. Getting this error on the browser's console:

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404 (Not Found)

under this error, it says:

```
dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js:177
xhrAdapter  @   xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)        
request @   Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js:76
wrap    @   bind.js:9
(anonymous) @   productActions.js:8
(anonymous) @   index.js:8
dispatch    @   VM69:14608
(anonymous) @   HomeScreen.js:18
invokePassiveEffectCreate   @   react-dom.development.js:23487
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:4056
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js:23574
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11276
flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js:23447
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:23324
workLoop    @   scheduler.development.js:417
flushWork   @   scheduler.development.js:390
performWorkUntilDeadline    @   scheduler.development.js:157
```

What is going on? Something related to the route api/products is not working but I havw no idea what that could be.

This is my server.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");

connectDB();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "API running..." });
});

app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

productRoutes.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const {
    getProducts,
    getProductById,
} = require("../controller/productControllers");

router.get("/", getProducts);
router.get("/:id", getProductById);

module.exports = router;
```

productControllers.js file:

```
const Product = require("../models/Product");

const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const products = await Product.find({});
        res.json(products);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
    }
};

const getProductById = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

        res.json(product);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Server Error" });
    }
};

module.exports = {
    getProducts,
    getProductById,
};
```

EDIT

The client code where I send the request:

```
import * as actionTypes from "../constants/productConstants";
import axios from "axios";

    export const getProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            dispatch({ type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST });
    
            const { data } = await axios.get("/api/products");
    
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
                payload: data,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({
                type: actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_FAIL,
                payload:
                    error.response && error.response.data.message
                        ? error.response.data.message
                        : error.message,
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: What's a port number that your Express server is listening to? Is it 3000, or 5000 (as specified as a default port number in your code)

Comment: I wanted it to be 5000, that is what I wrote in my server and my env diles. I don't know why the error message says "GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Can you post the client code where you send the request? @MrFacundo

Comment: Of course. It's now on the question

Comment: In the meantime, I tried to guess what can be the cause, the third point in my answer is your case :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, make sure your server is running on port 5000. You can check it by reading the log `Server running on port ...`
- Then, you can do a simple test in Postman to make sure the server and the route work correctly.
- If the 2 things above work, this is likely a problem on the client-side for me. Somewhere in your client code, you're sending a request like this :

```
fetch('/api/products')
```

It could be axios or another syntax/library. The important is by specifying only `'/api/products'`, the request will be sent to the current host. And the React application is hosted on `localhost:3000`, that's why you have the error.

In this case, you should provide the full URL (I adapted the syntax based on your client code) :

```
 const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/products");
```

Comment: Nice, changing this line made the request go to port 5000.

Now I have this issue :(

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: You may need to add more detail in your question about the new error. Based on your setup, I think it could be an issue with [CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968152/cross-origin-request-blocked-with-react-and-express)

Comment: Indeed. The first answer in the link solved the issue.

Also, my server was not working properly due to an error in the .env file:

PORT=5000; instead of PORT=5000