# Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes. Node.js server Angular front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

Im trying to enable CORS on a localhost site for a Node.js server with an Angular client.

I keep getting:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/api/v1/users' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

I've tried:

- app.use(cors())
- the app.use function from here: https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html
- the specific app.use function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34346592/1634753) with origin='localhost:4200'
- the app.use function with origin='*'

My current node server.js file:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors');

const port = 3000

///////
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT, GET, POST');
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});

///////
app.get('/*', (request, response) => {
  response.send('Hello from Express!')
})

app.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

My Angular method that is calling the node route (I know this is working because I get the cors error in chrome console shown above):

```
this.http.get<string[]>('localhost:3000/'+'api/v1/users').subscribe(x=>this.data=x);
```

Comment: Add the proxy settings like: 
https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/

Comment: Use `this.http.get<string[]>('http://localhost:3000/'+'api/v1/users').subscribe(x=>this.data=x)` (with `http://` protocol part included) instead of just `this.http.get<string[]>('localhost:3000/'+'api/v1/users').subscribe(x=>this.data=x)`

Comment: @Sudhakar that solution worked for me. Want to write it up and propose it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

For testing you should use a CORS browser plugin. The benefit of this is, that you dont have to modify the code when you want to build the code for prod