# CORS error, unable to send request to API

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Below is my code and I am unable to figure out why I get >net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
TypeError: Failed to fetch

```
 const signup=(user)=>{
        // console.log(name,email,password);

        fetch(`${API}/signup`,{
            //we can write whatever we are gonna send to backend here
            method:"POST",
            mode:'cors',
            headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*",
                Accept: "application/json",
            },
            body:JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(response=>{
            return response.json()
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
        });
    };
```

This is my Request Headers from network
**
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36
**

Here's my APP.js, i have added cors package at the last and also implemented it the last, have a look into it too.

```
require('dotenv').config() //allows us to use the env variables in the main file.
const express =require('express'); //express is used to configure routes 
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const morgan=require('morgan'); //used as middleware
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
const expressValidator=require('express-validator');
const cors=require('cors'); //providing a Connect/Express middleware that can be used to enable CORS with various options.

//import routes
const authRoutes=require('./Routes/Auth');
const userRoutes=require('./Routes/User');
const categoryRoutes=require('./Routes/Category');
const productRoutes=require('./Routes/Product');

//app
const app=express();


//db
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,{
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    UseCreateIndex:true
}).then(()=>console.log("Database Connected"));


//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cors());


//routes
app.use("/api",authRoutes);
app.use("/api",userRoutes);
app.use("/api",categoryRoutes);
app.use("/api",productRoutes);


const port=process.env.PORT || 8000

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: I believe you'd want Accept to be quoted. Not that I think it would help with your problem, but still you're referring to a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

In Cross Domains, Unless server have cors support, Client cannot make requests to that server. So we should have the server configuration.-By @Vishnu

Try to add below line also in the headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

If it doesn't work try to use cors in app

```
import cors from 'cors';
app.use(cors);
```

OR

```
var app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: In Cross Domains, Unless server have cors support, Client cannot make requests to that server. So we should have the server configuration as @Syed said above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Vishnu

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty new to react...have i added the part correctly?

headers:{
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*",
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"*", 
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
                
            },

Comment: Also i have tried the other two methods and both of them didnot work.

Comment: Past you app.js also

Comment: I did post it, please have a look

Comment: Try to put app.use(cors()); above app.use(bodyParser.json());

Comment: delete node_modules and then try npm install... shouldn't give the same error

Comment: @SyedMohibUddin
 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"*", 
  "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

Is this correct way of adding them into headers?

Comment: it shows error in vs code. and also is there any other way to solve this error?

Comment: Try to remove        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method": "*", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"*", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"

Comment: Show me your $API

Comment: @SyedMohibUddin export const API=process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;     this is $API

Comment: REACT_APP_API_URL what is this I meant and please try console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL) if its not undefined

Comment: That's the URL to my backend API

Comment: Oh maann! I want the base url like 'https://someapi' you are sending me the key not the value

Comment: I have a .env file and that has `REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost/8000/api`
Then a config file which is exporting this as `export const API=process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL;` So then i'm exporting yhis API into the js file to access the url

Comment: I get the following when i use firefox, i hope this gives you any idea
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/8000/api/signup. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: Firefox have some known issues with cors try to remove all from headers expect                 "Content-Type": "application/json",

Comment: I tried that too, didnot work. Is there some other way i could remove that error?

Comment: I went and tested cors at `https://webbrowsertools.com/test-cors/` and it showed `cors is blocked requestname(ex. get)`

Comment: Ok then I came found something different see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65643422/14004764

Comment: Try it with chrome

Comment: Tried with chrome and firefox, same isssue.

Comment: `https://github.com/Mehul-Kumar-Agarwal/E_Commerce`

Here use this link