# storing and retrieving data,achieved through REST to mongodb using fetch on node

Tags: node.js, rest, express, fetch

```
methods: {
onclicksubmit: function () {

const user = {
    firstname: this.firstname
  }
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  };
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', options).then(response => {
    console.log('success', response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
},
```

When I click on the submit button it should send the data to the database but there is an error appearing which says 'failed to fetch.'
This is the backend code:

```
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/register', function (req, res) {

  res.send({
firstname: req.body.firstname,


  })
  console.info("Request body: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));

  db.collection('user').insertOne(req.body, req.body.firstname, function (err, res) {
      if (err) return console.log(err)
      else res.send('success!')

      console.log('saved to mongodb');


    })
});
```

Comment: hard to say without looking at what `http://localhost:3000/register` is doing? Are you able to access this urk successfully using postman?

Comment: yes postman is working

Comment: does it give something more about error? like inner error etc.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It says "Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/register' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: when you try to access a url from browser which is not in the same domain you get this error.  Follow this link - it should fix issue for you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311469/1021796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to make a request to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. When you are using postman they are not restricted by this policy.

You could use code like this to enable CORS.

```
// Add headers
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // Website you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8888');

    // methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

    // headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    next();
});
```

OR

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.post('/register', cors(), (req, res, next) => {
})
```

Comment: Where do I add this after app.usebodParser.json()) because there are still errors appearing when I put it after this code.

Comment: try with `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` port 8888 was just an example.

Comment: Yes I tried that and I also changed the port to 3000. But it's still not working. It says 'failed to fetch'.

Comment: added another simple way, try that

Comment: Yes it looks like its working now. Thank you so much.