# AXIOS Call to Access to XML File Over Network

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to read an xml file on web server with axios api call. If I copy the xml file URL on a web browser, it opens xml contents. But if I use axio.get to call that URL, I get "Network Error", "CORS Missing Allow Origin".
Below is my code:

```
const url="https://mydomain/folder/myxmlfile.xml";
await axios
  .get(url, {
    withCredentials: false,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS",
      "Content-Type": "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
    },
  })
  .then((response) => console.log(response.data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

What am I missing here? Please advise! Thanks.

Comment: Is there an error on your server side with how your accepting headers in app.use (express)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311469/6388582

Comment: Error: Network Error  Error: Network Error
    createError createError.js:16
    handleError xhr.js:117
    dispatchXhrRequest xhr.js:114
    xhrAdapter xhr.js:15
    dispatchRequest dispatchRequest.js:58
    request Axios.js:108
    method Axios.js:129
    wrap bind.js:9 .... I don't understand these. I have no problem to call API URL in other reactjs app. But this xml file gives me the error.