# Unexpected Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cors

I'm following a simple tutorial from here:

http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

I have a node.js server running on a localhost port 4711

I have tomcat running on port 8082 and a backbone.js app as client started as index.html on that server.

But I get :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... api/books. Origin localhost:8082 is not
>   allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

1) **Why?**  This is not file based access - indeed a plain web browser will see

> htttp://localhost:4711/ and interact just fine.

2) **What's the fix?** (Given that part of this stack is a node.js server)

Comment: pass header value for Access-Control-Allow-Origin as '*'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initiating a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) request since the two servers are listening on different ports( index.html on localhost:8082 and your node server on localhost:4711)

In your node's http server, try setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*` or to the `Origin` header.

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers['origin']);
    //handle
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. So is this standard practice when using node.js ? (Because each node.js going to have its own port number.)  Or could somehow I persuade my Tomcat server to server data from node.js?

Comment: Whenever you need to perform an Ajax request to a domain different than the origin domain, you use `CORS`. This is not specific to `node.js` and can be used on any other server as well.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Do I need to alter both client and server (node js) code or is something that can be done from one side only.  Is there a definitive answer anyone can point me to for a Backbone client and Node.js server.

Comment: I found this answer to be the  most useful. This allows one to do everything from the NODE.js side. There are other approaches using horrid jquery magix on the client side - I would avoid those! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046364/origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin/16046714#16046714