# Access-Control-Allow-Origin on node.js WITHOUT Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

To solve error 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

So I tried to search for Access-Control-Allow-Origin for Node.js, but I could only see those using Express.js api.

The warning looks like very simple: add header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to the response.

[Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046364/origin-http-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin?rq=1)

Like the question above, I could also see many answers have app.use or res.header but:

1. I don't know where the app. comes from
2. res.header doesn't work for

   http.createServer(function (req, res){ "Something" });

Also, I tried

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Content-Type': 'text/html','Content-Length':data.length});
```

But doesn't work.

I know this problem can be solved on the client side, like security off option for chrome or add on. But I want my server gives service on any client so that the users don't need to do any setting on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the manual:

[HTTP Node.js v0.10.30 Manual & Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value)

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});
```

Sidenote: app is mostly coming from `var app = express();` I guess.

Comment: It seems I tried this once before, and yes, don't know why, this doesn't work too. I tried to ut res.setHeader at the beginning, in the middle of req.on, and at the end of my code. Also tried to put just before the res.write(data).

Comment: @TechNew headers need to be sent at the beginning of the response. Can verify wether the header really doesn't get sent through your browsers dev console?