# CORS - Using AJAX to post on a Python (webapp2) web service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jquery, cors, webapp2

This is going to be long:

Ok so I'm developing a google calendar gadget which sends requests to a Python webapp2 REST api hosted on Google App Engine.

The problem comes when I try to POST something it doesn't allows me because of CORS.
In Chromes' DevTools it says:

```
Method: OPTIONS.

Status: (failed) Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Origin https://hq34i4geprnp5vci191ljfuhcoerscl4-a-calendar-opensocial.googleusercontent.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I'm aware that this is because of CORS. Here:

[Ajax - 'Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534640/ajax-origin-localhost-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

It says that I have to add

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

To the headers, but then again I'm new to ajax and I wonder if it's done this way:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://myapp.appspot.com/service",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
        success: function(data) {
              alert("AJAX done");
        }
    });
```

Adding this headers the output is **different** (which makes me wonder if the origin has been allowed, though I don't really know):

```
Method: OPTIONS.

Status: (failed) Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myapp.appspot.com/service. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

I've even found this:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

Which lets me do GET requests, but I'd like to learn how to do them without this.

Also on my webserver I have this:

```
...
    class webService(webapp2.RequestHandler):
         options(self):
               self.response.write('options')

         post(self):
               self.response.write('post')

    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage),
        ('/service', webService)
    ], debug=True)
```

I don't know if I must add something more to the webserver, nor I've found info saying that I have to.
Also I think I'm near to achieve the CORS request but, I can't find THE Example that explains it all.

Please help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok I fixed it.

First of all I realized [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) that the headers were sent by the server so I was doing wrong when sending those headers in the AJAX request.

Finally, after searching around the worldwide web I found what I was missing. It was something stupid. I found the page that fixed it all:

http://enable-cors.org/server_appengine.html

So finally everything looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://myapp.appspot.com/service",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        alert("AJAX done");
    }
});
```

And in the webService:

```
class webService(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):      
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        # do something

    def post(self):     
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        # do something

    def options(self):      
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE'
```

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out a detail that might help others:

Browsers differ in how they handle the "Access-Control-Allow-Orgin" header. For example, I found that Chrome blocks cross domain posts when the header value is a wildcard (*) as in the solution code above. It considers it too liberal and wants a specific origin. Yet, other browsers such as IE and FireFox did not care.

So if you want to build a cross browser solution it would be best set the value of "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to the Origin value sent with the request.

If you're using SSL then you'll encounter some other differences that will need to be tested as well.

And if you need a lightweight solution this can all be done with POJS (plain-old-JavaScript) without resorting to jQuery. Just wire up the window.XDomainRequest for IE8+ and the window.XMLHttpRequest for other browsers and you're in business.

Answer (score 2):

Can simpler with [dispatch](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/handlers.html#overriding-dispatch) method

```
class BaseRequestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
        webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)

class LoginHandler(BaseRequestHandler):
    def login(self):
        #code here
```