# webapp2 and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, webapp2

I'm using webapp2 in a google app engine app. Basically I have built a REST API and I am trying to connect to it from a javascript ajax client. The problem I am facing is in how to correctly implement the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header thing. I have a solution that works but looks pretty clunky to me. Can anyone suggest a better way?

Here is my current solution:

in my main routing file i have:

```
webapp2.Route(r'/<v>/logins/simple',
                      handler=controllers.login_c.LoginController,
                      name='simple_login', handler_method='simple_login',
                      methods=['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS']),
```

and then in the controller:

```
class LoginController(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def simple_login(self, v):
    self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
                                     'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
    self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE')
    self.response.headers.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    if not self.request.__str__().startswith("OPTIONS"):
        ...more code
```

But this solution means i have to duplicate the headers thing in each controller. Can't I have something to catch all the OPTIONS requests?

Answer (score 2):

Was going over this today, and the OP's question:

> Can't I have something to catch all the OPTIONS requests?

...is one that I had, too. I created a wrapper class that my restful endpoint classes could inherit from, and it includes a default `OPTIONS` handler. This can also be done in the `dispatch` method as well, as demonstrated in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44879427/1058612).

*main.py*

```
import webapp2

from controllers import widgets_controller

APP = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/rest/widgets/all', widget_controller.All),
    ('/rest/widgets/create', widget_controller.Create),
], debug=True)
```

*widgets_controller.py*

```
class Create(rest.RestHandler):

    def post(self):
        # We use this for any POST, PUT, and DELETE, where necessary.
        self.decorateHeaders();

        # Handle the rest of the request here...
```

*rest_controller.py*

```
class RestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def decorateHeaders(self):
        """Decorates headers for the current request."""
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization')
        self.response.headers.add_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE')

    def options(self):
        """Default OPTIONS handler for the entire app."""
        self.decorateHeaders()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why route all to a single method: simple_login. Why not use a def options(self) in your handler?

I use something like:

```
class RPCHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def options(self):
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'

    def post(self):

        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, OPTIONS'
        .... more code to handle the rpc ....

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage),
        ('/rpchr', RPCHandler),
        ], debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example taken from some old webapp Python 2.5 application for handling json requests. But it is working fine for a couple of years now.

from app.yaml:

```
- url: /rpchr                     
  script: main.py
  secure: always

- url: /                          
  script: main.py
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

But now we have cloud endpoints.