# Google Cloud Endpoints v2 enable CORS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to support cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) calls on my API written using Google Cloud Endpoints Framework v2 in Python, but I am not able to do it.

According to [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/migrating), CORS is enabled by default, but I can't make any calls from a different origin using Javascript, I get this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/apiname/v1/events. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I've tried adding response.headers like [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760224/cors-using-ajax-to-post-on-a-python-webapp2-web-service) does, but it's not working either.

Does anyone know how I can enable CORS in my API?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SO link you posted mentions that the CORS headers need to be sent by the server.

You have to send the http header: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" with value of "*" or "your client domain".

You can either send this header from the Extensible Serviceble Proxy (ESP) which is part of the Google Cloud Endpoint, or you can send the http header from your server side api script.

I would recommend sending the header from the webserver, since the ESP may cache the api responses.

Comment: Hi Nadir, thanks for your help! I have tried with `response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'`in the methods of my endpoint API class, but that doesn't seem to work, I never see those headers in the response to my requests, any idea why this might not be working? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Inaki. You are welcome. Its possible that the nginx proxy is caching your api response. You can try to add the response headers to the nginx.conf file of your Cloud Endpoint Nginx Proxy. Add the following: add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' .http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-send-custom-http-headers/

Comment: Can that be done in the "Endpoints on App Engine Standard Environment"? Or only using Compute Engine? Thanks!

Comment: The Extensible Service Proxy is a simple nginx web server, so It should be possible to update the nginx.conf on both App Engine and Compute Engine